# asp.net websecurity custom fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

hello im very new asp and c sharp.

i would like to know how to add custom fields to the database like first name and phone number.

I've tried many different techniques but i get all types of errors.
I've found the website im using the easiest to follow and understand i see that they have mentioned adding custom fields but i don't know how to implement it.

i don't feel like changing my code but if i must and i will.

the code im using is off of this website:
http://www.thecodingguys.net/tutorials/asp/webpages-membership

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is actually easier than you think, first in the users table add two new fields like FirstName and PhoneNumber. Then on the [thecodingguys.net registration page](http://www.thecodingguys.net/tutorials/asp/webpages-membership-registration-page) look for this code:

```
var token = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(email, password, null, true);
```

Now the null means extra information like PhoneNumber, Name is not needed however since you want it you need to change it. The data type must be an array. So above that put this

```
var user = new{FirstName = firstname, LastName = lastname, Number = number};
```

Now the FirstName is the column name in the table and after the = sign is the HTML control getting this information. (You will need to add extra HTML boxes)

This is how it should look

```
var user = new{FirstName = firstname, LastName = lastname, Number = number};
var token = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(email, password, user, true);
```

There you go this should solve your issue, please mark as solved!